# Redirect query url to new page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this url

```
www.example.com/nothing_here?registration=disabled
```

and I want to redirect it to

```
www.example.com/errors/418.php
```

I cannot get rid of the nothing_here part of the url. How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your **document root**, add:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/nothing_here$ /errors/418.php?
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^registration=disabled$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^nothing_here$ /errors/418.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The first one I cannot use, because I don't want to redirect all nothing_here pages. The second one I have put at the top of my root htaccess but the url is not rewritten. Any ideas why? Thanks